# Retrieving a StringSet value using DynamoDB.DocumentClient in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

The `DynamoDB.DocumentClient` automatically marshals & unmarshals values between JavaScript types DynamoDB's more descriptive `AttributeMap` type.  However, when working with an Item that has a `StringSet` attribute, it does not seem to do the conversion automatically.

When adding a `StringSet` attribute to the table using `DocumentClient`, I use the `createSet(...)` method to convert the array to a Set.  When retrieving the value back, what is the inverse of `createSet(...)`?  Is the best practice to just access the Set's `.values` directly?  And if so, is that documented somewhere?

Here's sample code adding an Item with a `StringSet` attribute, then retrieving that item:

```js
    const docClient = new DocumentClient();
    const TableName = "StringSets-Example";
    const PK = "Names";
    const Values = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"];

    const putParams = {
        TableName,
        Item: {
            PK,
            names: docClient.createSet(Values)
        }
    }
    await docClient.put(putParams).promise();

    // ... some time later, I can retrieve the value with ...

    const getParams = {
        TableName,
        Key: { PK }
    }
    const result = await docClient.get(getParams).promise();
```

The `result.Item` there is a `Set` object, whereas I would expect it to be the same array I passed into `createSet(...)`.

If interested in seeing this live, [this repo has a fully-functioning example.](https://github.com/pwagener/dynamodb-stringsets)  Clone it, `npm install`, and run `index.js` and you'll see something like:

```
 $ ./index.js 
Running On: darwin 19.6.0
Node version: v12.20.0
AWS SDK version: 2.799.0
-------------------------
Creating table "StringSets-Example"
Waiting for "StringSets-Example" status to be "ACTIVE"
  Table status is: CREATING
  Table status is: ACTIVE
Put String Set "["Peter, "Paul, "Mary"]" into "StringSets-Example" with key "Names" and attribute "names"
Retrieved Item with key "Names" from "StringSets-Example"
The raw Item:  {
  PK: 'Names',
  names: Set {
    wrapperName: 'Set',
    values: [ 'Mary', 'Paul', 'Peter' ],
    type: 'String'
  }
}
The raw Item.names.values: [ 'Mary', 'Paul', 'Peter' ]
-------------------------
Done.  To clean up, run:
    ./src/deleteTable.js
```

Comment: Hey Peter. I created an array, and then used the document client to create a set. Then, I used the put function to put into dynamo, then retrieved it by using the query function. The value of the set is exactly the same as it was prior to storing into dynamodb. Am I missing something?

Comment: More likely that I'm missing something, I think!  See the code in the same repo for how I'm handling it.  This is what I'm doing to fetch it back, for instance:  https://github.com/pwagener/dynamodb-stringsets/blob/main/src/getStringSetValue.js .

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have here is to avoid the `DocumentClient` and the `createSet(...)` method.  Here's a sample using [AWS SDK V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html):

```
const key = { PK: `SampleNames`, SK: `SampleNames` };
const names = new Set([`Peter`, `Paul`, `Mary`]);
const item = { ...key, names };
const marshalledItem = marshall(item);

console.log(`Raw item: ${inspect(item)}`)
console.log(`Marshalled item to PUT: ${inspect(marshalledItem, { depth: 4 })}`)
const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
await client.send(new PutItemCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: marshalledItem,
}));

const { Item } = await client.send(new GetItemCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: marshall(key),
}));

console.log(`Returned item: ${inspect(Item, { depth: 4 })}`);
console.log(`Unmarshalled returned item: ${inspect(unmarshall(Item))}`);
```

The console output from there is:

```
Raw item: {
  PK: 'SampleNames',
  SK: 'SampleNames',
  names: Set { 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Mary' }
}
Marshalled item to PUT: {
  PK: { S: 'SampleNames' },
  SK: { S: 'SampleNames' },
  names: { SS: [ 'Peter', 'Paul', 'Mary' ] }
}
Returned item: {
  PK: { S: 'SampleNames' },
  SK: { S: 'SampleNames' },
  names: { SS: [ 'Mary', 'Paul', 'Peter' ] }
}
Unmarshalled returned item: {
  PK: 'SampleNames',
  SK: 'SampleNames',
  names: Set { 'Mary', 'Paul', 'Peter' }
}
```

... which makes a lot more sense to me.  I expect using the `marshall`/`unmarshall` methods from [AWS SDK V2's Converter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html) module would work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a marshaling issue, the order of a String Set is undefined:

This is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

**The order of the values within a set is not preserved.**